# Long exact sequence of homotopy groups for a pair $(X,A)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (A)$-module

Tags: algebraic-topology

Recall that for a pair $(X,A)$, there is the following long exact sequence
$\cdots \longrightarrow \pi_2 (A)\longrightarrow \pi_2 (X)\longrightarrow    \pi_2 (X,A)\longrightarrow \pi_1 (A)\longrightarrow \pi_1 (X)\longrightarrow \pi_1 (X,A).$
Also, I know that $\pi_1 (A)$ acts on $\pi_n (X,A)$ and $\pi_n (X)$ for all $n$.

It is clear from the definitions that $\pi_1 (A)$ acts on the
whole long exact sequence of homotopy groups for $(X,A)$, the action commuting
with the various maps in the sequence. (see Hatcher's book, p. 345). Can we conclude that the above long exact sequence a sequence of  $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (A)]$-modules and $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1 (A)]$-homomorphisms?

If so, $\pi_1 (A)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (A)$-module. But $\pi_1 (A)$ is not abelian generally. I was wondeing if someone could explain it to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only higher homotopy groups become $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(A)$ modules. It doesn't work for the fundamental group.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for the comment. So what does Hatcher mean by "it is clear that from definitions that $\pi_1 (A,x_0)$ acts on the whole long exact sequence of homotopy groups for $(X,A)$"? Doesn't  it act on $\to \pi_1 (A)\to \pi_1 (X)\to \pi_1 (X,A)$?

Comment: Yes, it acts. But not every action induces $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(A)$ module structure. For that to happen the action has to be compatible with the targets group operation, which doesn't hold even when $\pi_1(A)$ is abelian.

Comment: @freakish Now I got it. Thank you very much for your help.